# How can I access an expression in an AngularJS directive?

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to make a directive that looks like this (passing in an expression):

```
<button ui:spin="form.submitting">Save</button>
```

But am unsure if it's possible (or how) to access the form.submitting expression. In the past I've done something like this:

```
<button ui:spinner-button ui:spin="form.submitting">Save</button>
```

Where I read the uiSpin attribute in the uiSpinnerButton directive, but I'd like to know how to do this "all in one"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, my directive looks like:

```
.directive('uiSpin', function() {
    return {
        link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

            scope.$watch(attrs.uiSpin, function() {

                // do stuff here...

            });
        }
    }

})
```

I based this off the source to `ngShow`: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngShowHide.js

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to reference it by defining the directive's scope as follows:

```
scope: {
    spin: '=uiSpin'
}
```

Inside the directive's linking function, it will be `scope.spin`.

Comment: Should be `spin: '=uiSpin'`

Comment: Forgot to mention, I'd like to do this with a non-isolated scope.

Answer (score 1):

For a non-isolated scope, use [$parse](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24parse):

```
myApp.directive('uiSpin', function($parse) {
   return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var model = $parse(attrs.uiSpin)
      console.log(model(scope));
      // If you want to change the value in your directive:
      model.assign(scope, "???");
   }
});
```

If you don't need to modify the value, you can simply use $eval instead:

```
console.log(scope.$eval(attrs.uiSpin));
```

Comment: Feel like this is close, how can I watch for changes, something like: scope.watch(function() { return scope.$eval(attrs.uiSpin); }, function() { console.log('uiSpin changed'); }); doesn't seem to work,

Comment: That should work (missing `$` in front of `watch`?)  You can also watch `model`: `scope.$watch(model, ...)`, or as you already discovered, you can watch the attribute: `scope.$watch(attrs.uiSpin, ...)`.